# Superscript and Subscript in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, subscript, superscript

I'm trying to show "H2O" with the 2 in subscript in a PivotItem Header.

E.g.

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="H20">
</controls:PivotItem>
```

I'd also like to assign the same value from code behind to TextBlock.Text.

E.g.

```
textBlock1.Text = "H2O"; // 2 to appear as subscript.
```

Is this possible with the version of Silverlight used for WP7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some searching around I found a solution.

From [SubScript and SuperScript in TextBlock](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/64169/482157.aspx/1?Re%20SubScript%20and%20SuperScript%20in%20TextBlock) by [Troels Pedersen](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/561550.aspx) and [lordcheeto](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/482157.aspx) respectively.

In the XAML the subscript 2 can be expressed via Unicode.

E.g.

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="H&#x2082;0">
</controls:PivotItem>
```

And similarly for the code behind.

E.g.

```
textBlock1.Text = "H\x2082O"; // 2 appears as subscript.
```

There are some limitations on this approach as only characters in the Basic Multilingual Plane (0000-FFFF) are supported and the font being used also needs to support the characters.